# HighStock how to know with multiple measures on callbacks which measure got changed?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighStock with the stock tools measure tool. I'm having multiple measurements and like to show additional information for each measurement outside the graph and update the additional information on change of the measurements.

However I could not find any information on the documentation which measurement got changed.

On the callback, is there any possibility to know which measure got changed?

Does the stock chart has a property where I can get a list of all measurements and their related axis values?

```
navigation: {
    bindings: {
        measureX: {
            end: function(e) {
                //gets triggered when the measure event ends
            }
        }
    },
    annotationsOptions: {
        events: {
            afterUpdate(e) {
              //gets triggered when the measure event updates.
            },
            remove(e, annotation) {
               // gets triggered when the clicked on the remove icon
            },
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: All annotations are saved in the `chart.annotations` array. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4gjs7p9e/ If you need more help - could you reproduce your case on some online editor that I could work on?